# per-request session in meteor server?

Tags: node.js, meteor, node.js-connect

I am adding an auth layer and I think I have it figured out except for one tricky detail.
My Meteor app doesn't have any routes but I've added a hook into the connect middleware so that the "/" route errors if there isn't a correct API token.  If the token is okay then I call `next()` to forward the route to Meteor.

The problem is that, depending on the token, I need to set  server-side parameters for the connection, and I don't know how to do this. For example, say I have a static list of API keys mapped to permission levels. If a user sends a request with "ADMIN_API_KEY" then I would like to set `Session.permission_level = "admin"` for use by the Meteor server's functions. `Session` is just for the client in Meteor, though.

```
  # this code's in coffeescript

  WebApp.connectHandlers.use '/', (req, res, next) ->
    validator = new RequestValidator(req, next)
    validations = [
      "valid_namespace",
      "only_https"
    ]
    error = validator.validate(validations)
    next(error)
    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    # Here I want to set some config option which can be
    # read by the server in the same way it can read things like
    # Meteor.user()
```

In Rails I would just say `session[:permission_level] = "admin"`. But it seems to not work this way in Meteor.

By the way, I am not using a Routing package yet in Meteor, though if that would make this easier than I would.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `Session` I've been doing something like

```
import { DDP } from 'meteor/ddp';
import { DDPCommon } from 'meteor/ddp-common';

export const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = identifyUser(req); // parse the request to get the token you expect
  if (!userId) {
    return next();
  }

  DDP._CurrentInvocation.withValue(new DDPCommon.MethodInvocation({
    isSimulation: false,
    userId,
  }), () => {
    next();
    // in that context, Meteor.userId corresponds to userId
  });
};
```

for my REST api and that works well regarding the user Id and being able to call Meteor function that should be invoke in a DDP context, like `Users.find(...)`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a logged in user at this stage, so I could not have a valid user id

Comment: I see. I'm not sure what's the best way forward to be able to use things like Session that look global but are actually linked to a specific context. I've ended up passing all parameters and using Meteor as a simple node backend in those cases

Comment: Looking into the methods available to meteor I see there is uid, which is basically sessoon id

Comment: Using some storage I could use this to inplement session.